# Setting Environment Variables for React Application in Dockerfile Not Working as Expected

Tags: docker, kubernetes

This is my Dockerfile for client (frontend):

```
FROM node:18-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
ARG REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST
ENV REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST=$REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I deployed it on Kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-frontend
  labels:
    app: client-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: client
        image: daniel135dang/client:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: app-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-frontend-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: client-frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

And here is my backend deployment using Rest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rest-backend
  labels:
    app: rest-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rest-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rest-backend
        image: daniel135dang/rest:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "5000"
            
          - name: APP_NAME
            value: "rest"

          - name: HOST
            value: "rest-service"

          - name: RABBITMQ_HOST
            value: "amqp://rabbitmq:5672"

          - name: RABBITMQ_FILE_LOCATION_EXCHANGE
            value: "uploaded_file_location"

          - name: RABBITMQ_OUTPUT_LOCATION_EXCHANGE
            value: "output_location"

          - name: POSTGRES_HOST
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: services-config
                key: POSTGRES_HOST

          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: services-config
                key: POSTGRES_USER

          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: services-config
                key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD

          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: services-config
                key: POSTGRES_DB
          
          - name: ROOT_DIR
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: services-config
                key: ROOT_DIR

          - name: REACT_APP_SERVICE_LIST
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: app-config
                key: REACT_APP_SERVICE_LIST

          - name: GUIDELINES_LIST
            value: "chapter_title,format_check,page_count"

          - name: GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: services-config
                key: GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET
              
          - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: services-config
                key: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rest-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: rest-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

And finnaly is the app-config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-config
data:
  REACT_APP_SERVICE_LIST: "word_frequency,chapter_title,format_check,chapter_summarization,page_count,table_of_content,citation,table_figure_detection"
  REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST: "http://rest-service:5000"
```

When I start to deploy (on minikube), it maybe sent to wrong ports:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV4Pd.png)
It client port:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OIgy.png)

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)?